# Subject of "Rain is forecast for tomorrow"

Tags: passive-voice

Please clarify the subject in the sentence below.

> Rain is forecast for tomorrow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the sentence says that "a rainy whether is expected to happen tomorrow" . According to Cambridge dic: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/forecast_1

Comment: Thank you Hakan but still I don't know how to find the subject.

Comment: The sentence is in passive voice, and *[r]ain* is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much Damkerng T.Would you please explain how you found it?

Comment: (who or what) is (forecast)? -> Rain

Comment: Thank you orekelens. I was confused. I thought it must be the forcaster (Which is absent in that sentence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm:

> In the active voice, the subject and verb relationship is straightforward: the subject is a be-er or a do-er and the verb moves the sentence along. In the passive voice, the subject of the sentence is neither a do-er or a be-er, but is acted upon by some other agent or by something unnamed (The new policy was approved).

And:

> A sentence cast in the passive voice will not always include an **agent** of the action. For instance if a gorilla crushes a tin can, we could say "The tin can was crushed by the gorilla." But a perfectly good sentence would leave out the gorilla: "The tin can was crushed."

Comment: Thank you BobRodes. Do You say that "Rain" is not the subject?

Comment: No, it is the subject as the others have said.  Look at the second sentence of the first quote.  Rain is acted upon (the forecast "acts upon" the rain) by something unnamed.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: @user3214 you should award Bob the bounty on this

Comment: That site is really great, especially for native speakers who need to brush  up their Shakespeare...